# PyParsing: shell style space escape using backslash

Tags: python, escaping, backslash, pyparsing

i have a need to parse text that is a space delimited key value pair in the form of

```
<key>=<value> <key>=<value> ...
```

which is pretty straight forward with pyparsing.. except when the values can have spaces in them 
eg.

```
dog=blue cat="orange tangerine" mouse=a\ small\ grey\ mouse
```

what would a pyparsing grammar look like for the last pair
pyparsing is greedy on spaces..
it's further complicated by line spanning text which may look like

```
dog=blue cat="orange tangerine" mouse=a\ small\ grey\ mouse \
   lion=nonexistent
```

I looked at a few examples at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/share/view/7002417 
and [Python/Pyparsing - Multiline quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962093/python-pyparsing-multiline-quotes) which helped with multi-line text but not with backslash-escaped-space

Comment: So, not only can the values have spaces, but they may or may not be surrounded by double quotes?

Comment: Correct, if they're surrounded by quotes, that's easily handled by pyparsing's QuotedString()

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input strings are in a file called "input.py", the following works for your examples:

```
import pyparsing
from pyparsing import ZeroOrMore, Group


OP_EQ   = pyparsing.Literal('=').suppress()
DQUOTE  = pyparsing.Literal('"').suppress()
ESPACE  = pyparsing.Literal('\\ ').suppress().leaveWhitespace()
BSLASH  = pyparsing.Literal('\\')

S       = pyparsing.Word(" \t\r\n").suppress().leaveWhitespace()

DELIM   = ZeroOrMore(S ^ BSLASH).suppress()

KEY     = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums)("KEY")

VALTOK  = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.printables, excludeChars='="\\')

QVALUE  = ( DQUOTE +
            Group(VALTOK + ZeroOrMore(S + VALTOK)) +
            DQUOTE
            )
NQVALUE = Group(VALTOK + ZeroOrMore(ESPACE + VALTOK))
VALUE   = (NQVALUE ^ QVALUE)("VALUE")

PAIR    = Group(KEY + OP_EQ + VALUE)("PAIR")

PAIRS   = (PAIR + ZeroOrMore(DELIM + PAIR))

with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()

res = PAIRS.parseString(lines, parseAll=True)

for (k,v) in res:
    print('{} = "{}"'.format(k, ' '.join(v)))
```

Output:

```
dog = "blue"
cat = "orange tangerine"
mouse = "a small grey mouse"
dog = "blue"
cat = "orange tangerine"
mouse = "a small grey mouse"
lion = "nonexistent"
```

And as XML, for reference:

```
<PAIRS>
  <PAIR>
    <KEY>dog</KEY>
    <VALUE>
      <ITEM>blue</ITEM>
    </VALUE>
  </PAIR>
  <PAIR>
    <KEY>cat</KEY>
    <VALUE>
      <ITEM>orange</ITEM>
      <ITEM>tangerine</ITEM>
    </VALUE>
  </PAIR>
  <PAIR>
    <KEY>mouse</KEY>
    <VALUE>
      <ITEM>a</ITEM>
      <ITEM>small</ITEM>
      <ITEM>grey</ITEM>
      <ITEM>mouse</ITEM>
    </VALUE>
  </PAIR>
  <PAIR>
    <KEY>dog</KEY>
    <VALUE>
      <ITEM>blue</ITEM>
    </VALUE>
  </PAIR>
  <PAIR>
    <KEY>cat</KEY>
    <VALUE>
      <ITEM>orange</ITEM>
      <ITEM>tangerine</ITEM>
    </VALUE>
  </PAIR>
  <PAIR>
    <KEY>mouse</KEY>
    <VALUE>
      <ITEM>a</ITEM>
      <ITEM>small</ITEM>
      <ITEM>grey</ITEM>
      <ITEM>mouse</ITEM>
    </VALUE>
  </PAIR>
  <PAIR>
    <KEY>lion</KEY>
    <VALUE>
      <ITEM>nonexistent</ITEM>
    </VALUE>
  </PAIR>
</PAIRS>
```

**Edit**: FWIW, you could do this in regex:

```
import re

with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()

mat = re.sub(r'=([^"]\w*(?:(?:\\ )\w*)*)', r'="\1"', lines)  # Quote unquoted values
mat = mat.replace("\\ "," ").replace("\\\n","")              # Replace escaped spaces
mat = re.findall(r'(\w*)="(.*?)"', mat)                      # Extract pairs
for (k,v) in mat:                                            # Print pairs
    print('{} = "{}"'.format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
dog = "blue"
cat = "orange tangerine"
mouse = "a small grey mouse"
dog = "blue"
cat = "orange tangerine"
mouse = "a small grey mouse"
lion = "nonexistent"
```

Comment: :) yes, Regex would be much shorter.. however this is part of a larger parser.. This solution works well.. I omitted the parseAll=True for non multi-line use cases. I didn't realize you could use '\\ ' itself as a parseable fragment. In hindsight it makes sense. Thanks much, this save me tons of research time.